# module not found error for an installed package

Tags: python

I installed BeautifulSoup4 and Pyinstaller using pip but when I try to import any of them I get a ModuleNotFound Error but I followed all the installation requirement I checked online to see if I could find similar errors but couldn't find any. Please, any advice would be helpful thanks for your support.

I have checked the path for all my packages and nothing seem to be wrong with it because I only have this error on these packages mentioned above.

> > > import beautifulsoup4
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >           import beautifulsoup4
> > >       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'beautifulsoup4'

Comment: use "import bs4"

Comment: make sure you use the correct version of python in your source code